# Structured Logging Analyzer/Viewer

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog, structured-logging

I have an ASP.NET Minimal API that uses Serilog as a logging provider.

I use for development the normal console logging and for Test/Staging/Prod a combination of stdout and structured file log (JSON format).

My problem or question is, how can I analyze big structured logging files and view or search in them?
My goal is to quickly analyze my log files for exceptions, warnings, or the behavior of requests.

My files are +1 GB big.

What tools are you using on your projects?
Is there a better solution for logging in .NET?

I search mostly for open-source solutions, best in slot would be docker stuff.

Comment: "My files are +1 GB big" - you should really consider configuring "rolling files" to avoid unmanageable files.

Comment: Product/service recommendation questions are expressly off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options I can think of for accessing large structured log files, for example: ELK Stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana), Seq, Loggly, Graylog.

It may be worth looking into these.

Comment: fyi this isn't really a valid answer (as it's just a few product names). Also, product recommendation questions are off-topic.